# Which topological property am I looking for?

Tags: algebraic-topology, semialgebraic-geometry

I just started reading about topology and semi-algebraic sets, so please forgive me if this is a naive question:

Given a bounded and closed semi-algebraic set, which topological property guarantees that it is possible to shrink the set's boundary towards any point within the set without intersecting holes? (My guess so far: connected and contractible set).

Also: are there practical ways to determine whether this property holds for a given bounded and closed semi-algebraic set?

Comment: Can you define what you mean a bit more? For example, does an annulus satisfy this property?

Comment: I would say it doesn't since it has a hole in it which parts of the boundary would have to cross when being contracted towards some point. On which aspects should I be more specific?

Comment: I’m not sure, it’s just the way you’ve stated shrinking is quite odd. Doesn’t every hole pose a problem? Are you just looking for whether the set is simply-connected?

Comment: Yes, every hole is a problem. At first, I thought that I was looking for simple connectivity, but then I found that this does not rule out holes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space): 

"The definition only rules out handle-shaped holes. A sphere (or, equivalently, a rubber ball with a hollow center) is simply connected, because any loop on the surface of a sphere can contract to a point, even though it has a "hole" in the hollow center. The stronger condition, that the object has no holes of any dimension, is called contractibility."

Comment: Right, this is partly the reason what you stated is confusing - a sphere has no boundary, so saying it’s possible to shrink the boundary to a point doesn’t mean anything. It’s probable what you want is a contractible space, but it would be interesting to hear more about why you want to do this.